# wpa_supplicant fails to connect to peap network with reason 15

Tags: wpa-supplicant

I can't log into my university network.

Configuration:

```
network {
    scan_ssid=1
    ssid="apname"
    key_mgmt=WPA_EAP
    eap=PEAP
    ca_cert="/path/to/correct_and_verified_cert.pem"
    altsubject_match="DNS:xxx"
    identity="correct_identity"
    password="password"
    phase1="peaplabel=0"
    phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
}
```

Output of wpa_supplicant:

```
user@comp$ sudo wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/network.conf -i wlp4s0
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wlp4s0: Trying to associate with SSID 'apname'
wlp4s0: Associated with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=25
wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-METHOD EAP vendor 0 method 25 (PEAP) selected
wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=2 subject='/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert Assured ID Root CA' hash=HASHHASH
wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=1 subject='/C=NL/ST=Noord-Holland/L=Amsterdam/O=TERENA/CN=TERENA SSL CA 3' hash=HASHHASH
wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=0 subject='/C=XX/L=Loc/O=UNIV_ID Loc/OU=ZID KOM/CN=odo.XXX' hash=HASHHASH
wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-ALT depth=0 DNS:odo.XXX
wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-ALT depth=0 DNS:radius.XXX
EAP-MSCHAPV2: Authentication succeeded
EAP-TLV: TLV Result - Success - EAP-TLV/Phase2 Completed
wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-SUCCESS EAP authentication completed successfully
wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx completed [id=2 id_str=]
wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx reason=15 locally_generated=1
wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
```

This configuration is known to work on other systems.
I also tried to remove the ca_cert line in the config, to prevent
the verification of the certificate.

reason 15 means, that the 4 way handshake failed because of a timeout.

Does anyone have an idea what could have caused this problem?

- Linux Kernel Version: 5.1.9
- wpa_supplicant version: v2.8
- Wireless card: 04:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC (rev 01)
- Wireless card driver: brcmfmac

Comment: see: https://blog.stigok.com/2017/03/26/wifi-loses-connectivity-periodically-wpasupplicant-reason-4.html may help

Comment: @Bart Thanks for the input, but this person had a completely different hardware, and their problem was driver specific for that hardware, as far as I can tell by a cursory glance over the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So something broke between version 2.6 and 2.7 of wpa_supplicant.

Downgrading did the trick.

I'm running arch (surprise something broke), so I did the following:

```
sudo pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/wpa_supplicant-2\:2.6-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.gz
echo 'IgnorePkg=wpa_supplicant >> /etc/pacman.conf'
```

After fiddling with this for a little longer I found, that using `wext` instead of the new `nl80211` driver also solves this problem, even for version 2.8 of wpa_supplicant.